# Angualrjs 2 application to build cordova app

Tags: angular, cordova

Am having an Angularjs2 application, I want to build this application in cordova as hybrid mobile application(Android/ios). Is there any way to do this?
when i tried command `cordova build`, it throws error as **Directory is not a cordova-based project**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a cordova based application first. There is great documentation on how to do this on cordova' website here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

A couple of other things I thought I would mention is Ionic (https://ionicframework.com/). It uses cordova and the new version runs on Angular 2. But also gives you a framework with a bunch of build tools, components, native capabilities, and awesome deployment tools such as the Ionic Viewing App.

There is another framework that allows you to code in Angular 2 and write a mobile app called Native Script: https://www.nativescript.org/ I don't know much about this one, but where cordova and ionic are considered "hybrid" mobile apps, Nativescript compiles down to native code, similar to react native.

Comment: Now i have created a cordova app and run it successfully, now i want to add angular 2 in this. how to do.

Comment: This website isn't really a website where people walk you through how to create an entire app. If you don't know how to add angular 2 to a cordova app, I think you should try to just start by creating an ionic app like I mentioned above. It will create a cordova app with angular 2.